# How to write a meaningful typehint for a function that returns a filter?

Tags: python, filter, type-hinting, typing

Assume the following function

```
def get_list_of_nums_and_square_nums_with_last_digit_9() -> List[Tuple[int, int]]:
    sqr = lambda n: n * n
    is_last_digit_9 = lambda n: n % 10 == 9
    is_last_digit_of_square_num_9 = lambda t: (lambda n, n_squared: is_last_digit_9(n_squared))(*t)

    nums_and_square_nums = map(lambda n: (n, sqr(n)), range(10))
    return list(filter(is_last_digit_of_square_num_9, nums_and_square_nums))
```

which would return

```
>>> get_list_of_nums_and_square_nums_with_last_digit_9()
[(3, 9), (7, 49)]
```

. Now I want an equivalent function, but returning a iterator - or more specifically a filter:

```
def get_nums_and_square_nums_with_last_digit_9():
    sqr = lambda n: n * n
    is_last_digit_9 = lambda n: n % 10 == 9
    is_last_digit_of_square_num_9 = lambda t: (lambda n, n_squared: is_last_digit_9(n_squared))(*t)

    nums_and_square_nums = map(lambda n: (n, sqr(n)), range(10))
    return filter(is_last_digit_of_square_num_9, nums_and_square_nums)
```

Which type hints can I use so that we can clearly see the structure of the result, when the resulting filter is applied?
Is `Iterator[Tuple[int, int]]` correct? Or is there a more precise way to do it?
Somehow it should be possible to determine the elements' structure `Tuple[int, int]` from the typehint.

Comment: `Iterator[Tuple[int, int]]` looks right. `Iterable[Tuple[int, int]]` would work too. `filter` is also a class, not a normal function, so it can be used as the return as well (although it's not generic, so you can't type hints its "contents".

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks. For now I also used `Iterator[Tuple[int, int]]`, because it shows the elements' structure and `filter` doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to verify whether a given type annotation matches the implementation/usage of a function is to add the type annotation to the code and run a type checker on it.

```
from typing import Iterator

def get_nums_and_square_nums_with_last_digit_9() -> Iterator[tuple[int, int]]:
    sqr = lambda n: n * n
    is_last_digit_9 = lambda n: n % 10 == 9
    is_last_digit_of_square_num_9 = lambda t: (
        lambda n, n_squared: is_last_digit_9(n_squared)
    )(*t)

    nums_and_square_nums = map(lambda n: (n, sqr(n)), range(10))
    return filter(is_last_digit_of_square_num_9, nums_and_square_nums)
```

Running `mypy` on the above reports no errors, so it should be fine.  We can verify the returned type with `reveal_type`:

```
reveal_type(next(get_nums_and_square_nums_with_last_digit_9()))  # tuple[int, int]
```

If we used an incorrect annotation, e.g. using `list` when a `filter` is returned:

```
def get_nums_and_square_nums_with_last_digit_9() -> list[tuple[int, int]]:
```

then `mypy` will report:

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "filter[Tuple[int, Any]]", expected "List[Tuple[int, int]]")
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know this type checker.